# Quitar un texto especifico con CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

Estoy haciendo una pagina con Wordpress y al crear un menú como este (widjet) me lo crea de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe la posibilidad de quitar el ">" con CSS utilizando selectores o algo por el estilo?

Answer (score 1):

En efecto, como decia el compañero, la solucion la he encontrado en el inspector. Seleccionado el icono y buscando en las clases que aparecen a la derecha he seleccionado la clase (de unas 2-3 lineas de codigo por cierto) que contenia el icomoon y otras, despues he ido a la hoja de estilos y ha bastado con un `display: none;`

Comment: Igualmente,  tiene que revisar el resto de la pagina para mirar que no se halla ocultado también  en otra parte

Comment: Está bien. Es un widjet que solo he colocado en una pagina en concreto asi que ha quedado solucionado ya por fin. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo esta haciendo witdget,  le recomendaría primero revisar el script de functions.php y buscar el nombre del widget y verificar ya sea el nombre de la clase o si tiene el signo >.

La otra forma es mirar con la opción de Google Chrome de inspeccionar y hacer click en el icono de la flecha con un cuadrado e ir sobre el signo >,  hay puede saber que clase de CSS que la afecta.  Una vez teniendo el nombre de la clase va al el script de style.css  agrega al final la clase y le agrega

```
display:none !important;
```

Y listo,  lo único demorado es saber que clase afecta al signo >

Comment: No he encontrado el nombre del widjet en function.php. He probado el segundo metodo y desde el inspector no aparece si quiera el símbolo >. Es una etiqueta a que tiene un selector ::before que escribe lo que viene a continuacion del simbolo en cuestión.

Comment: Por favor tomele un pantallazo, en donde aparezca el inspector y y las clases que afectan ese signo

Comment: Acabo de añadir un pantallazo del inspector. No se si es eso lo que me has pedido.

Comment: No veo la imagen